# How can I disable Ctrl+Q for all applications (system wide)?

Tags: gnome, configuration, shortcut-keys, system

A lot of applications like Firefox, Chrome etc, get closed when I accidentally press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> because of the proximity of the *<kbd>Q</kbd>* and *<kbd>W</kbd>* keys on the keyboard. Is there a way this shortcut can be removed or reset on a system wide basis?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The best way is to disable the keyboard setting in your specific application. For Firefox there is an extension [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994). This allows you to change keyboard settings.

If you want to disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for your whole system, I would suggest to make a new setting:

1. Go to System -> Preferences -> Keyboard settings
2. Click **Add**
3. Give it a name like *fake setting* and enter `/bin/false` as command. Apply your changes.
4. Click on '**Disabled**' and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

Now you should have a new entry with your applied name and your keyboard setting. Every time you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> your system will run the command `/bin/false` which basically does nothing. So this is a workaround to disable the setting.

Comment: Awesome answer, and  how did you do the styled button shortcuts! :)

Comment: @jathanism: Use the `kbd` html tag.

Comment: When you want to press `Ctrl-Q` the window will close. You can never assign this key using this method

Comment: @AnwarShah -- I just tried this solution and it worked for me.

Comment: I'm using GNOME Shell 3.20.2 on Archlinux and this worked for me.

Comment: this is so hacky but it works splendidly. Ubuntu GNOME 16.04.

Comment: Fail. This doesn't let me use Ctrl+Q in an application that defines this shortcut by default (e.g. IntelliJ)

Comment: @MarkJeronimus: guess that's a problem of the application, then. But I'm sure you can disable that in IntelliJ as well.

Comment: I want it in IntelliJ because it's a standard shortcut across platforms

Comment: keyconfig no longer works in Firefox 57.

Comment: System-wide disable of `Ctrl+Q` is all that worked for me. I use the command `true`.

Comment: this works in ubuntu mate 20.04, but the program is named like "keyboard shortcuts"

Comment: I love this solution, but I modified it to use Ctrl+Q as "Hide Window" instead

Answer (score 9):

Probably inserting the shortcut under System -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts and "disabling" it should do the trick.

Comment: Instead of just typing away do a bit of research if your not 100% certain. It would have costed you 2 secs to find that it is not there.

Comment: Well, it is if you add it, isn't it? Maybe I didn't express myself correctly. But apparently, there *is* an easy fix since it's worked for me.

Comment: Maybe not, it is still not a very nice way to do it... This way you will never be able to use Ctrl+W for any thing! For instance in bash Ctrl+W means delete word backwards.

Comment: It does work and it is exactly what has been asked for. @LassePoulsen why should CTRL+W be affected from this?

Answer (score 5):

You can go to System → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* and assign this combo to an unused action. For example I assigned <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to switch to workspace 12 (no, I don't have 12 workspaces).

As a result this system wide setting overrides application one and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> no longer closes Firefox (likely the combo never reaches Firefox). It just does nothing.

Comment: Kind of a nice and easy fix, but I rather recommend to use a browser's extension. Using system preferences to override Ctrl+Q system-wide would result in some applications being unable to use that shortcut - e.g. you won't be able to use Ctrl+Q in IntelliJ IDEA to show documentation pop-up.

Comment: Well, the question is about disabling this combo system-wide not app per app ;).

Comment: And that's why you've got +1 from me... ;)

Answer (score 4):

For newer Firefox versions, you can disable it as follows:

1. Go to `about:config`.
2. Set `browser.quitShortcut.disabled` to `true`.
3. Restart the browser.

For other applications, the steps will differ. Chrome no longer closes on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, so there is no need to change anything there. Note that in many other applications, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is a useful shortcut, so disabling it system wide would break that functionality.

Answer (score 3):

My current workaround is to create a new shortcut in System Settings → *Keyboard* → *Shortcuts*. If the shortcut is accidentally pressed, we receive an informative message.

- Title: *Quit Prevention*
- Command: `notify-send 'Dear idiot' "Don't press ctrl-Q"`
- Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>

This disables the command system-wide, however, which might be an acceptable tradeoff depending on your use case.

The above is Tested in Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

If <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> closes the keyboard settings window, like it did for me, youi can do the following:

1. Set the shortcut to another value.
2. Close the window and wait until the updated shortcut appears somewhere in `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/keybindings/*`.
3. Open that file and edit the `stringvalue` of that command to read `&lt;Primary&gt;q`.
4. Reboot the PC.

This worked for me as opposed to the accepted answer.

Comment: Even that did not work for me. I tried the below:

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <gconf>
 <entry name="action" mtime="1369776357" type="string">
  <stringvalue>/bin/false </stringvalue>
 </entry>
 <entry name="name" mtime="1369776357" type="string">
  <stringvalue>dummy2</stringvalue>
 </entry>
 <entry name="binding" mtime="1369776299" type="string">
  <stringvalue>&lt;Primary&gt;q</stringvalue>
 </entry>
    </gconf>

Comment: I had to restart gnome session, but this worked, thanks!

Comment: Its very hard to understand

Answer (score 2):

Here is a command-line version of the already-supplied GUI version. On some systems <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will close the accelerator input window without setting the shortcut, so this can be needed:

```
gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/keybindings/inhibit_ctrl_Q/name "Inhibit Ctrl+Q"
gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/keybindings/inhibit_ctrl_Q/action /bin/false
gconftool-2 --type string --set /desktop/gnome/keybindings/inhibit_ctrl_Q/binding "<Primary>q"
```

Note that this solution is for GNOME 2/Unity. A similar solution should be possible with `gsettings` for GNOME 3.

Comment: It seems that these settings although preserved after restart does not provide expected behavior (Ubuntu 14.04). Also, after being applied, using Ctrl+Q shortcut with focused Nautilus window makes it hang/unresponsive.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux with Firefox Quantum, there is currently a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325692) that prevents extensions and explicit configuration from changing a built-in shortcut such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.

A workaround is to block it at the system level by e.g. installing the script from https://github.com/sasawat/firefox-ctrl-q-workaround and assigning it as the action of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as a global shortcut.

Comment: As of mid-2018, this must be the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me, disabling the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut system-wide is not the perfect solution, because it prevents applications other than Firefox, Chrome etc., to be notified when you use that shortcut. For example, IntelliJ IDEA uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as a default binding to show quick documentation pop-up.

If you are looking for a Firefox-only solution, I highly recommend [Disable Ctrl-Q Shortcut](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/disable-ctrl-q-shortcut/) plugin. In my opinion it's a better option than [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) mentioned by @qbi because its source is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/choobin/dcqs), while keyconfig is available only as a binary.

Answer (score -1):

My way is going to System → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* (yeah I know it's not there). Here you add one more shortcut with the *Name* "Do nothing", with a random *Command* with the *Shortcut* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. Then the deadly combo should not bother you anymore anywhere.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is not an appropriate solution because the command "a" will run every time Ctrl+Q is pressed. And it will override shortcuts of other applications too.