# Disable CTRL+Q in Firefox without keyconfig extension

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys

How do I disable the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut in Firefox without using the [keyconfig](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?t=72994) extension?

Comment: i hate developer, who develop ctrl+q(very rare used) with ctr+w(freq. used). Thanx for your request!

Comment: [Disable Ctrl+Q systemwide](https://askubuntu.com/a/1923/6514)

Comment: [Duplicate on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1352295/500826)

Comment: Not sure why this website doesn't let me add an answer, this question isn't that old.
The simplest solution is to just install xbindkeys and map CTRL+Q to /dev/null, or echo "" or something. It will trap and kill the combo before it ever has a chance to ruin your private-session pr0ning by sloppy left-hand typing. No more lost links... The only caveat is that it'll trap it for all other programs, too. In my arrogant opinion, a welcomed feature. edit: I just saw user31389's answer. My life is changed.

Comment: Now it's easy to turn it off by setting the option "browser.quitShortcut.disabled" to "true" inside the "about:config" page

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Firefox 87 you can just set `browser.quitShortcut.disabled` to `true` in `about:config`. If this preference is not present, just create a new boolean preference with this name and set it to `true`.

Relevant bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52821

Comment: note, that this will take effect only after restarting firefox for some reason.

Answer (score 44):

You should obtain a *similar result*, easier, enabling the *hidden* config option (about:config).

1. In Firefox's address bar, type **`about:config`** and accept the
   warning that it will give. Now it appears in front of you a long
   list of config options. Filter it typing the keyword  **quit** in
   the *filter bar* (up top).  After that the filter acts you will have
   only few lines. Click on **browser.showQuitWarning** and set it
   **true** by clicking on it.
2. You can use this filter again with the keyword **warnon** and see if
   the options "warn when close tabs" and similar are set to true.
3. In the Firefox's Options/**Preferences** (or Edit/preferences it depends from system and version), go
   to the **Tabs** section and check the option **"Warn me when
   closing multiple tabs".** This will prevent you to close a window with
   multiple tab.

You will not completely disable **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>** but at least you will make it harmless.

Comment: Unfortunately, for me (on Ubuntu 14.10 with Firefox 33.0), setting the key "browser.showQuitWarning" to "true" does absolutely nothing. :-( So I had to install the above mentioned extension just to disable keyboard shortcut. What a world we live in.

Comment: It just worked for me with 14.04.

Comment: 1Ubuntu 16.06 : does not work either.

Comment: @axd It should depend from the `firefox` version (or from the way in which you compiled from the source files) and not from the Ubuntu release... BTW 16.06 seems to be a [monthly snapshot-releases](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800310/what-is-ubuntu-16-05-16-06-etc) and not a stable one. The solution in the answer above worked or not in alternative phases depending on the firefox version and it does not rely on external *addons* but only on internal parameters.

Comment: Does not seem to work in Firefox 57.0.2.

Comment: @okolnost @axd @user905686 it won't work if you have firefox set to show your windows/tabs from last time. In General preferences under `When Firefox starts` - change that to home page or blank page. See https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1127960 for the reason why. You can restore the last session manually from the history menu when starting firefox.

Comment: 2018 update: There is no 'tabs' section. Searching for 'tabs' or 'multiple' did not bring up such an option, either.

Comment: I know newer Firefox versions removed the feature that allowed you to configure your keyboard shortcuts via a GUI. Is there any hidden way to configure keyboard shortcuts (i.e. via `about:config` or is there a Firefox config file), yes or no?

Comment: @DylanHunt in `about:config` you can find the field `browser.tabs.warnOnClose`. The default value is _true_... After so many years the layout of the interface is changed many times, but some internal variable not...

Comment: This stopped working for me recently. Odd.

Comment: Can confirm that this no longer works with Firefox 61 on Windows 7. Obviously not an Ubuntu-specific problem.

Answer (score 22):

There is now an extension just for that:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/disable-ctrl-q-shortcut/

**2020 update:**

The original extension has now disappeared from the addons store. Similar addons (see comments) have come and gone. One of the last remaining extensions [(link)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/disable-ctrl-q-and-cmd-q/) **does not work on Linux** due to: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1325692

Comment: For those who are interested in using this plugin, it is restartless.

Comment: Disable Ctrl Q shortcut seems to not be maintained. It does not support e10s. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/ctrl-shift-q-quit/ is a good alternative.

Comment: Neither of the two is compatible with Firefox 57.

Comment: Both are gone now.

Answer (score 13):

You can just **add a custom shortcut** for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>. In Ubuntu it is available directly in settings[(How to)](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html). It will be captured by the OS and hence no app including Firefox would detect it.

P.S. I have mapped it to play an 'Oops' sound.

Step 1. Install sox package & its mp3 support library-

```
sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all
```

Step 2. Add the following line in the custom shortcut prompt-

```
play ~/Music/Oops.mp3
```

P.S. For windows users: you can use [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/download/). It has inbuilt function to play a beep sound. Use it in the script like this-

```
^Q::
    SoundBeep, 1000, 500
```

The '^' above stands for Ctrl

Comment: thank you. this was far simpler than some of the other solutions, which wanted to intercept the keystrokes and pass them on based on what application I was in. While I can see why I might sometimes want to do that, this was a far easier solution for my case, and one I would not have thought of.

Comment: You're welcome! I figured this solution for the same reason :)

Comment: I must say, with all the existent 'disable-ctrl-Q' extensions not working due to some bugs in mozilla or due to  the version incompatibility; this answer is the best. Now I have a lovely 'Badum tsss!' sound every time I press ctrl-Q :)

Comment: The link to add a custom shortcut doesn't explain it any more for Ubuntu 20.04+. But I just used the settings->keyboard shortcuts and there I changed the setting for "hide Window" to CTRL+Q

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> isn't a Firefox specific shortcut, it's system wide on Ubuntu if you don't mind disabling it everywhere follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1919/how-can-i-disable-ctrlq-for-all-applications-system-wide).
 Basically, you create a new shortcut and assign `/bin/false` as command.

No restarting is needed.

Comment: No restarting is needed. only quitting.))

Comment: I think this is not a global shortcut any more since Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

## On Ubuntu: Hide window instead

In your global Ubuntu-Settings: `settings->keyboard shortcuts` change the setting for "hide Window" to CTRL+Q