# How can I disable Ctrl+Q shortcut in Ubuntu?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys, configuration, system

How can I disable <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut to close the current app in Ubuntu?

I have seen the top answer under:
[How can I disable Ctrl+Q for all applications (system wide)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1919/)
which suggests assigning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to `/bin/false/`.

I don't think this should be an accepted answer since some apps that use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> like IntelliJ IDEA won't work with this shortcut anymore.

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings close`
produces only <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>

I use Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Have you tried to create a [useless] shortcut for Ctrl+Q ? I think it would then execute this one instead of the default behaviour (overriding it).

Comment: This is exactly what suggested in the top answer under related post, but unfortunately this will break `Ctrl-Q` shortcut in IDEA.

Comment: The top answer's first suggestion is to disable it in your application. Ctrl+q indeed is an application level shortcut, as opposed to the system wide Alt+F4. If you disble it system wide, then obviously it also will not work in applications that use Ctrl-Q differently.

Answer (score 1):

It appeared that I mistakenly considered <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as a system-wide shortcut because it closed Firefox, files explorer and Atom editor.
But in fact, it is just a common shortcut for many apps, so it has nothing to do with Ubuntu/Gnome.
The solution in my case was to disable the shortcut separately in each app.